# How to self-compile a ruby extension that is included in a Gemfile: building charlock_holmes for Gitlab?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I run an installation of [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) on my ArchLinux server. GitLab depends on [charlock_holmes](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) for ICU support. Every time I update my system, this support breaks, because my ICU version is newer than the one GitLab/charlock_holmes use.

I am not a ruby programmer but I have taken a look at the source code and found that the extension is just compiled against the current `libicu`. However, just following the [upgrade guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/upgrader.md) executes `bundle install` which updates all the Gems. This does not build the extension again it seems.

In the end, after running an update, I get errors like this:

```
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': libicui18n.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so (LoadError)
```

This is to be expected:

```
$ pacman -Q icu
icu 54.1-1
```

I am now looking for way to simply perform an additional step when upgrading to a new version that will compile the charlock_holmes version against the new `libicu`. As long as nothing major changes in these releases that requires charlock_holmes to be updated first, this shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spent a while figuring this out so here you go.
I'm assuming installation paths used in the GitLab guide. Please note that I am not a Ruby developer and I have no idea if this is the correct way to do it but it works for me.

If you're using a version of Ruby other that 2.2.0, please fix that. The same goes for the charlock_holmes version.

```
rm -rf /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4

sudo -u git -H bundle exec gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/usr/lib/icu
```

Comment: This just gives me `Could not find charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.` when running the second step...